# DBSCAN Clustering algoruthm

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, dbscan

In DBSCAN  algorithm i get cluster labels as **-1** what does this mean? And how to find how many cluster is genrated when I use minpts=5 and eps=13.

Comment: What library do you use ? Please be precise in your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scikit-learn, the label -1 indicates **noisy samples**, according to the scikit-learn's documentation:  [sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html)
The method **fit_predict** returns a numpy array containing cluster labels. Therefore, the shape of this array indicates number of clusters. Fore more info, check the link above.
You can also check this tutorial from scikit-learn: [Demo of DBSCAN clustering algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py)